# k shortest paths implementation in Igraph/networkx (Yen's algorithm)

Tags: python, graph, path, networkx, igraph

After thorough research and based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828041/suggestions-for-kspa-on-undirected-graph) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15836361/1863061) and a lot more I was suggested to implement k shortest paths algorithm in order to find first, second, third ... k-th shortest path in a large undirected, cyclic, weighted graph. About 2000 nodes.

The pseudocode on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen's_algorithm) is this:

```
function YenKSP(Graph, source, sink, K):
  //Determine the shortest path from the source to the sink.
 A[0] = Dijkstra(Graph, source, sink);
 // Initialize the heap to store the potential kth shortest path.
 B = [];

for k from 1 to K:
   // The spur node ranges from the first node to the next to last node in the shortest path.
   for i from 0 to size(A[i]) − 1:

       // Spur node is retrieved from the previous k-shortest path, k − 1.
       spurNode = A[k-1].node(i);
       // The sequence of nodes from the source to the spur node of the previous k-shortest path.
       rootPath = A[k-1].nodes(0, i);

       for each path p in A:
           if rootPath == p.nodes(0, i):
               // Remove the links that are part of the previous shortest paths which share the same root path.
               remove p.edge(i, i) from Graph;

       // Calculate the spur path from the spur node to the sink.
       spurPath = Dijkstra(Graph, spurNode, sink);

       // Entire path is made up of the root path and spur path.
       totalPath = rootPath + spurPath;
       // Add the potential k-shortest path to the heap.
       B.append(totalPath);

       // Add back the edges that were removed from the graph.
       restore edges to Graph;

   // Sort the potential k-shortest paths by cost.
   B.sort();
   // Add the lowest cost path becomes the k-shortest path.
   A[k] = B[0];
return A;
```

The main problem is that I couldn't write the correct python script yet for this (delete edges and places them back in place correctly) so I've only got this far with reliyng on Igraph as usual:

```
def yenksp(graph,source,sink, k):
    global distance
    """Determine the shortest path from the source to the sink."""
    a = graph.get_shortest_paths(source, sink, weights=distance, mode=ALL, output="vpath")[0]
    b = [] #Initialize the heap to store the potential kth shortest path
    #for xk in range(1,k):
    for xk in range(1,k+1):
        #for i in range(0,len(a)-1):
        for i in range(0,len(a)):
            if i != len(a[:-1])-1:
                spurnode = a[i]
                rootpath = a[0:i]
                #I should remove edges part of the previous shortest paths, but...:
                for p in a:
                    if rootpath == p:
                        graph.delete_edges(i) 

            spurpath = graph.get_shortest_paths(spurnode, sink, weights=distance, mode=ALL, output="vpath")[0]
            totalpath = rootpath + spurpath
            b.append(totalpath)
            # should restore the edges
            # graph.add_edges([(0,i)]) <- this is definitely not correct.
            graph.add_edges(i)
        b.sort()
        a[k] = b[0]
    return a
```

It's a really poor try and it returns only a list in a list

I'm not very sure anymore what am I doing and I'm very desperate with this issue already and in the last days my point of view on this was changed with 180 degrees and even once.
I'm just a noob doing its best. Please help. Networkx implementation can also be suggested.

P.S. It's likely that there are no other working ways about this because we researched it here already . I've already received lots of suggestions and I owe the community alot. DFS or BFS wont work. Graph is huge.

Edit: I keep correcting the python script. In a nutshell the aim of this question is the correct script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a python implementation of Yen's KSP on Github, [YenKSP](https://github.com/Pent00/YenKSP). Giving full credit to the author, the heart of the algorithm is given here:

```
def ksp_yen(graph, node_start, node_end, max_k=2):
    distances, previous = dijkstra(graph, node_start)

    A = [{'cost': distances[node_end], 
          'path': path(previous, node_start, node_end)}]
    B = []

    if not A[0]['path']: return A

    for k in range(1, max_k):
        for i in range(0, len(A[-1]['path']) - 1):
            node_spur = A[-1]['path'][i]
            path_root = A[-1]['path'][:i+1]

            edges_removed = []
            for path_k in A:
                curr_path = path_k['path']
                if len(curr_path) > i and path_root == curr_path[:i+1]:
                    cost = graph.remove_edge(curr_path[i], curr_path[i+1])
                    if cost == -1:
                        continue
                    edges_removed.append([curr_path[i], curr_path[i+1], cost])

            path_spur = dijkstra(graph, node_spur, node_end)

            if path_spur['path']:
                path_total = path_root[:-1] + path_spur['path']
                dist_total = distances[node_spur] + path_spur['cost']
                potential_k = {'cost': dist_total, 'path': path_total}

                if not (potential_k in B):
                    B.append(potential_k)

            for edge in edges_removed:
                graph.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1], edge[2])

        if len(B):
            B = sorted(B, key=itemgetter('cost'))
            A.append(B[0])
            B.pop(0)
        else:
            break

    return A
```

Comment: It does take me one step closer to the solution because I can analyse how he stored-deleted the edges and then he added them back. Anyway it's very hard to follow this example because it calls upon the scripts he wrote for a DiGraph involving many libraries there that hopefully are not that necessary in this case (including libraries calling for outside functions I think). I continue to approach this to Igraph and we will see. Thank you. It might be the answer but I don't see it yet. I analyse it.

Comment: I've managed to build it after spending time with the algorithm on Wikipedia and on the base of this example above. Only have to take care while using Igraph (and probably other librarys too) that in the method it's better to use a deep copy of the graph. That way it will not mess up the original graphs edge ID-s when you add the edges back so you can continue work with it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you so I ported Wikipedia's pseudocode for Yen's algorithm for use in Python with the igraph library.

You can find it there : https://gist.github.com/ALenfant/5491853